# Excel: Simple method to do partial matches that are 1-2 characters off?

Tags: excel, vlookup, text-mining

I tried searching for a solution to this but was unable to find one. In Excel, I have a table with a column of messy data (like "sperry�") and I'm trying to match each entry to a table that has the cleansed version of the data (like "sperry®"). Most of these are just 1-2 characters off and can appear anywhere in the word (ex. "Est�e"). I'm sure there's a solution to this with VBA but I'm not proficient with it and was wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Thanks!

Comment: How about Search/Replace (CTRL-H in my version of Excel)? It also has a Options dialogue where you can set something more. It's possible to copy that one bogus character and the good replacement there. This solution is good for one-time repairs.

Comment: I've thought about that too but the � could be a ™, ô, é, etc. For example, in the above example, if I replaced all the � with ®, I would get "sperry®" correct but "Est®e" incorrect because it should be "Estée."

Comment: Seems excel doesn't have search replace with regex (like word does afaik), but this may help you: http://superuser.com/questions/630692/does-excel-have-find-replace-match-placeholder

Comment: This would be a highly unreliable method, but if nothing else works you could loop through each letter in the word, then loop through each word in the table you wish to match, looping through each letter in those words...and then create some sort of matching algorithm...like sum the counts of the letters, or see what percent of the letters exist in comparison to the other word and then match it with the highest "match percentage"...that might be a little more involved than you'd like though.